# Java GC memory remove

Tags: java

I'm currently writing a java socket server and i was wondering what will happen in the next situation:

**mainClass** create **Lobby** class and add it to an array in the **mainClass**.

the **Lobby** class create a **Room** class and add it to an array in the **Lobby** class.

the **Room** class hold a reference to the **Lobby** class.

the **mainClass** remove the **Lobby** instance from the array

the lobby hold reference to the room and the room hold reference to the lobby, will they ever be cleaned up by the gc?

Comment: The GC should be called the *root reference-able objects retainer.* If an object doesn't have strong references from the GC roots, it can be cleaned up regardless of ciruclar reference.

Comment: Modern garbage collection is much more complicated than simple reference counting. Basically the heap is searched for reachable, "alive" objects; and anything else is garbage. Hint: such things are documented a zillion times ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objects don't have some references from GC Roots, they will be deleted.